# What is the best Solr update strategy?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Being new to Solr i am feeling unsure about how I can update Solr. I have an existing (version 4) Solr cloud solution that uses Zookeeper. Now I want to update to version 7.2.1. I am wondering what my strategy should be. I dont care about downtime during the update.

So far I am thinking:

1. Get latest version of Solr & Zookeeper
2. Recreate my Solr collections using the collections API
3. Copy my old collection files (including the specific schema files) into the newly created collection folders. Not sure if this should work out-of-the-box.

I am in doubt if this is a sensible strategy and/or I should have any concerns doing in this way. I would like a strategy that I can use for future updates as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If by 'copy my old collection files' you also mean index data there, that won't work. Solr 7.x should be able to read only Solr 5.x and later index, so if you want to upgrade you need to:

1. Upgrade to Solr 5.X or 6.X
2. Then upgrade to Solr 7.X
3. Or you could try to use [this script](https://github.com/cominvent/solr-tools/blob/master/upgradeindex/upgradeindex.sh) from a Solr commiter to do it for you. This does not mean you might need to change your schema/solrconfig to be able to load the upgraded collection in 7.x.

That being said, if your corpus is not too dificult to reindex, I would strong ly suggest:

1. review your schema, fix deprecations etc, and change it to use newer features (many new types that were not available in 4.x)
2. then do a full reindex

Comment: I am not so worries about index data as my data will be reindexed after the update. I just want the schemas to be ok after the update.  Fixing deprecations is obviously necessary. Should i be able to just copy the schemas to the collection folder?